# angular server side validation, how to find the form element from the object reference

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms, validation

I have a complex form with client and server side validations. lets assume the form is as simple as:

```
<input type="text" name="name" ng-model="object.name"/>
<div ng-repeat="order in object.Orders">
    <input type="text" name="value{{$index}}" ng-model="order.Value"/>
    <input type="text" name="descr{{$index}}" ng-model="order.Descr"/>
</div>
```

The actual form is much more complex than this and all the client side validation is working, my problem is when the user submits the form via an http ajax request then server returns validation errors in json format, like:

```
{ errors: [ { desc: "Invalid value", path: "object.Orders[0].Value" } ] }
```

I can easily get the object reference for the path returned by the server but, how can i get the form element so i can mark it invalid within angular?

I particular i wan't to set the form element $invalid. because the form is complex and i have many of thouse forms i wan't to make an automatic way of finding the form element from the object path `object.Orders[0].Value`.

Can anyone help me with this

Comment: what are you using for serverside validation??

Comment: I'm using webapi and entity framework for model validation and some custom validation for business rules. but the format returned by the server is always the same and very similar to the format that i've posted in the question

Comment: so you are using data-annotation for model validation or some framework like fluent validator?? you will have make the format on server to be more inlined with what properties are having errors etc..

Answer (score 0):

Create the new `ErrorObjetct` and when you get the response assign that error response to that object and use that object like bellow.

```
<input type="text" name="name" ng-model="object.name"/>
<div ng-repeat="order in object.Orders">
    <div>{{ErrorObject.value}}</div>
    <input type="text" name="value{{$index}}" ng-model="order.Value"/>
    <div>{{ErrorObject.descr}}</div>>
    <input type="text" name="descr{{$index}}" ng-model="order.Descr"/>
</div>
```

Comment: that's a way of doing it, but because of the complex object tree the error object will have to reside inside the tree itself i.e `{{order.error.value}}`. and i wanted to use angular form validation to make client and server side validation behave the same way. i will accept this answer if no other fulfills what i intent to do. thank very much for your answer :)

Comment: If you provide me full structure then i can help you. Need code for thaty

Answer (score 0):

1. if you want to show errors on form level and not field level, then just have some status bar where you can show these errors. It will be quick and a global solution. [read here - at very bottom](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1033076/Integrating-AngularJS-with-ASP-NET-MVC)
2. if you want to show errors on field level and not on form level then you will have to change the format of error message, they should include the name of the property which caused the error + error description
   then loop thru the form and each model attached to form and push error to $form.$model.$error array, to have tight integration with server side validation. But this solution would be difficult to make global, given that you might have multiple forms being validated same time. so you might need just one line of code for every form where on error of $http you synchronize errors from server with $form. [READ HERE](http://www.jerriepelser.com/blog/remote-client-side-validation-with-fluentvalidation)

Its too vast topic to provide a working sample, the links should get you going